# how to give confirm message box when selecting previous date in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

hello i have created one webpage in asp.net & in that webpage i am using Asp calendar control. I want to display message box whenever user selects the previous dates from that calendar control how can i do it please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Selection_Change event of the calender control:

```
void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
         if(Calendar1.SelectedDate < Date.Now)
         {
             Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('previous date selected');</script>);
         }
}
```